# Remapping [ and ] is really slow

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

I have remapped `[` and `]` to easily cycle through my open buffers. I don't understand why when I use this shortcut there is a delay of almost a second before the buffer is switched. This doesn't happen when I use `gn` or `:bnext`. 
This is how do mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> ] :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [ :bprevious<CR>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: There are many other mappings that start with `[` and `]` so Vim is waiting to see if any more keys are going to be pressed. You can see a list of square bracket commands see `:h [`. Vim unimpaired uses `[b` and `]b` for buffer commands if you are looking for ideas.

Comment: You can consider using a leader key (I use space) and map <leader> [ and ].

Answer (score 4):

This is because you probably have other mappings that start with `[` or `]`.

You can get a list of all your active mappings by running `:map`.

You then have to get rid of the maps you don't want that start with `[` (either in your vimrc or by finding out how to change the mappings for the plugin).

If you prefer, you can also remap to something more specific, for example `[[` or `]]`

Comment: There are actually built-in bindings that start with `[` and `]` (in fact, `[[` and `]]` are among them), so they wouldn't show up with `:map [`.